# How to convert a JavaScript function into a jQuery one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript function and I want to have the same but in jQuery but it's not working correctly, the list items are not appearing:

```
function showList(section, books) {
  let olBooks = document.createElement("ol");
  let liBook = null;

  for (let book of books) {
    liBook = document.createElement("li");
    liBook.id = value.id;
    liBook.classList.add(CLASS_BOOK);
    liBook.innerHTML = "<p>" + booksInHTML(book) + "</p>";
    olBooks.appendChild(liBook);
  }
  section.append(olBooks);
}
```

With jQuery is not working:

```
function showList(section, books) {
   var olBooks = $("<ol/>");

    $.each( books, function( index, value ) {
     var liBook =  $("<li/>");

     liBook.id = value.id;
     liBook.classList.add(CLASS_BOOK);
     liBook.text("<p>" + bookInHTML(value) + "</p>");
    olBooks.append(liBook);
  });
  section.append(olBooks);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the `id` property with jQuery, you need to use `.prop` (or, less desirably, `.attr`):

```
liBook.prop('id', value.id);
```

Also, to set the class of an element with jQuery, use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
liBook.addClass('CLASS_BOOK');
```

Also, to set the HTML of an element with jQuery, use the `.html` method. If you use the `.text` method, the result will set the *text content* of the element, not the HTML:

```
liBook.html("<p>" + bookInHTML(value) + "</p>");
```

But concatenating HTML strings from possibly untrustworthy user input can allow for arbitrary code execution, which is a security risk - it's also inelegant. Consider selecting the `<p>` first, and setting its `.text`:

```
$("<li><p></p></li>")
  .appendTo(liBook)
  .prop('id', value.id)
  .addClass(CLASS_BOOK)
  .find('p')
  .text(bookInHTML(value));
```

Live demo:

```js
function showList(section, books) {
  var olBooks = $("<ol/>").appendTo(section);
  $.each(books, function(index, value) {
    $("<li><p></p></li>")
      .appendTo(olBooks)
      .prop('id', value.id)
      .addClass(CLASS_BOOK)
      .find('p')
      .text(bookInHTML(value));
  });
}

const CLASS_BOOK = '';
const bookInHTML = arg => arg;
showList(section, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section"></div>
```

Comment: As an explainer, `$("<li/>")` syntax doesn't create a regular DOM element, but rather a jQuery collection containing the new element, where you can operate on with jQuery API.

Comment: Thanks but like that the list items also don't appear.

Comment: This should also work:
`$("<li/>")
.prop('id', value.id)
.addClass(CLASS_BOOK)
.append($("<p/>")
.text(bookInHTML(value))
.appendTo(liBook);`

Comment: @John maybe the DOM isn't there when your code is running. Is your code wrapped in a `jQuery.ready()`?

Comment: @John Works fine here, see snippet